# Vega-Lite - What is the best way to work with large amounts of data?

Tags: vega, vega-lite

I'm using **Vega-Lite** to visualize a large amount of data in a JSON format. I have ~16,000 data items in the data section.

I'm placing both the data and the graph code in a single JSON (~20,000 lines) in the [Vega online editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/custom/vega-lite).

The problem is that with this amount of data, the visualization crushes.

Is there a better way to use Vega to present this amount of data or best practices I need to consider for using this amount of data?

Answer (score 1):

No, Vega-Lite is currently not well-suited for visualizing larger datasets. There are efforts to improve on this, namely https://github.com/vega/scalable-vega.

Follow along there (and contribute!) if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

I often create HTML dashboards for SharePoint and intranets with JSON data arrays that exceed 100k rows.

If you load your data into JavaScript function you can very efficiently aggregate (sum, count, max, min, avg etc) 100k rows in < 2 secs then pass this array to vega-lite.

Here is a sample aggregate function:

```
function APBAggregate(data, columns, aggregateType = 'sum', topN = 20) {
    const numberOfColumns = columns.length;

    const aggFunc = {
        sum: (a, b) => a + b,
        count: (a) => a + 1,
        max: (a, b) => Math.max(a, b),
        min: (a, b) => Math.min(a, b),
        avg: (a, b, countObj, key) => {
            countObj[key] = (countObj[key] || 0) + 1;
            return (a * (countObj[key] - 1) + b) / countObj[key];
        },
        distinct: (a, value, set) => {
            set.add(value);
            return set.size;
        }
    };

    const roundToTwoDecimal = (num) => Math.round(num * 100) / 100;

    if (numberOfColumns === 1) {
        const key = columns[0];
        if (aggregateType === 'distinct') {
            const distinctValues = new Set(data.map(item => item[key]));
            return distinctValues.size;
        }
        return roundToTwoDecimal(data.reduce((acc, item) => aggFunc[aggregateType](acc, item[key]), 0));
    }

    if (numberOfColumns === 2) {
        const [key1, key2] = columns;
        let countObj = {}; 
        const grouped = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
            if (aggregateType === 'avg') {
                acc[item[key1]] = aggFunc[aggregateType](acc[item[key1]] || 0, item[key2], countObj, item[key1]);
            } else {
                acc[item[key1]] = aggFunc[aggregateType]((acc[item[key1]] || 0), item[key2]);
            }
            return acc;
        }, {});
        return Object.entries(grouped)
            .sort(([, valA], [, valB]) => valB - valA)
            .slice(0, topN)
            .map(([value, total]) => ({ [key1]: value, value: roundToTwoDecimal(total) }));
    }

    if (numberOfColumns === 3) {
        const [key1, key2, key3] = columns;
        const grouped = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
            acc[item[key1]] = acc[item[key1]] || {};
            acc[item[key1]][item[key2]] = (acc[item[key1]][item[key2]] || 0) + (aggregateType === 'count' ? 1 : item[key3]);
            return acc;
        }, {});
        return Object.entries(grouped)
            .map(([value1, subGroup]) => ({
                [key1]: value1,
                values: Object.entries(subGroup).map(([value2, total]) => ({ [key2]: value2, value: roundToTwoDecimal(total) }))
            }))
            .sort((a, b) => b.values.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.value, 0) - a.values.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.value, 0))
            .slice(0, topN);
    }

    return [];
};
```

I would then use this function with the below code that would give me a top 25 rows based on VESSEL, TYPE and COUNT of EQUIPID.

```
var ChartData01Temp = apbAggregate(myDataSource,['VESSEL','TYPE','EQUIPID'],'count',25); 
const ChartData01 = ChartData01Temp.flatMap(entry => 
entry.values.map(subEntry => ({
G1: entry.VESSEL,
G2: subEntry.TYPE,
G3: subEntry.value
}))
);
```

Vega lite:

```
var V1Spec = {
"$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
"data": {"values": ChartData01},
```

I also use a Devextreme datagrid to view and filter my json data and then the charts are updated automatically. This is a very efficient way of handling many rows and is much, much faster than using the vega-lite transforms.